# Does c++ provide a way to make a whole struct constant (non-modifiable)?

Tags: c++, struct, types, constants, type-declaration

So far, I know that I can make all the struct members `const`. But can I write somewhere `const` once and have all the members turned to `const`?

In other words, I want all the struct instances to be `const` even if I forgot to add `const` modifier in a variable declaration.

```
const struct Foo {}
```

The above doesn't work due to `const can only be specified for objects and functions` error;

Comment: What advantage would this have over `struct Foo {}; const Foo f;`?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: @Quentin please see the second paragraph (added it now)

Comment: Terminology: `const` is a "qualifier" not a "modifier".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While you can't make a whole type `const` you can make an alias to that type with a `const` qualifier.

```
struct Foo {};
using ConstFoo = const Foo;
ConstFoo myFoo; // Same as const Foo myFoo;
```

Here, `ConstFoo` acts as a type that is always `const`.

If you'd rather keep `Foo` as a `const` type, you can use

```
using Foo = const struct {};
```

Comment: Great Idea, thanks! Again shows me how flexible C++ is.

Comment: but `auto` breaks stuff `auto foo2 = myFoo;` :-/

Comment: @Jarod42 does it? Works well for me. However if you mean that `foo2` becames modifiable, well that's a copy of (not a reference to) a const variable, shouldn't it behave this way anyway? But, yes, the struct itself is not really const...

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev But if the intention is for all `Foo`s to be `const`, using `auto` can bypass that. It allows you to get a non-`const` instance. You are right that it doesn't expose the original (`MyFoo`) to modification.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Understood, thanks. But I am almost not using *copying* in my code anyway, so it's fine-ish, I guess (we don't have alternatives anyway).